# CCK add form theme customization

Tags: 7, nodes, forms

I would like to customize the node add form of the CCK theme for these reasons:

- It is a very large customization job.
- I'd like to place my fields in my own way instead of trying to do this with css.
- I also need to use [Bootstrap](https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap) for responsive design.
- I also need to add some classes to labels and text fields.

Can anyone give any pointers on how to achieve this?